# On memory intensive on-demand compute

Tags: aws-lambda, azure-functions

We are considering using azure functions to run some compute on. However our computes could take up lots of memory, lets say more than 5GB.

As I understand there is no easy way to scale azure functions based on memory usage. Ie If you reach 15GB start a new instance (since you don't want it to run over the maximum memory of your instance)?

**Is there a way around this limitation?**

OR

**Is there another technical alternative to azure functions that provide pay per use and allows rapid scaling on demand?**

Answer (score 0):

Without any further details about what you are actually trying to compute, it is very hard to give you any meaningful advice.

But there are a few things you could consider.

For example, if you are processing CSV files and you know you need 1GB of memory to process a file, then "spin up" a AWS Lambda per file. You could use serverless orchestration like [AWS Step Function](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) to coordinate your processing. This way you are effectively splitting up your compute intensive tasks.

Another option would be to automate "pay per use" yourself. You could use automation tools like [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io) to start a [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) spot instance, run your computing task and after it finishes just shut down the EC2 instance. That is more or less pay as you go with a bit of operations overhead on your part.

There are also other services like [AWS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/?nc=sn&loc=0&whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc&fargate-blogs.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&fargate-blogs.sort-order=desc), which are marketed as "Serverless compute for containers", allowing you to run Docker containers in a pay per use manner. Fargate allows provisioning of up to 30GB of memory.

Another option would be to use services like [ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) or [Memcached](https://aws.amazon.com/memcached/) to "externalize" your memory.

Which of these options would be the best for you is hard to tell, because it depends on your constraints: do you need everything to be stored in the "same memory" or can it be split up etc, what are your data structures, can it be processed in chunks (to minimise memory usage), is latency important, how long does it take, how often do you need to run your tasks, etc...

Note: There are probably equivalent Azure services to the AWS services I talked about in this answer.